# How to split a file into two UNEQUAL parts in windows xp?

Tags: splitter

I know about all the file splitting programs which split the files into equal parts.

But i need to split a file say 783kb into 2 parts

Part1 : 105kb 
Part2 : 680kb

is there a program to do this ? in Windows XP

Thanks

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: for Windows XP operating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the file into parts of 105kB, for example using `split` from [GNU CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), and then assemble all but the first part.

---

Or you could, from the same package, use `head` to output only the first *xxx* Bytes from a file to another file called `myFileHead`:

```
head -c xxx myFile > myFileHead
```

The same applies to `tail`, only writing the last *xxx* Bytes to a file called `myFileTail`:

```
tail -c xxx myFile > myFileTail
```

Comment: Actually, I need to split a 1400mb file into Part1:115kb Part2:theremainingfile.. so this method will be consuming huge time if used..

Comment: I doubt it, that's merely a one-liner in Bash.

Comment: the previous comment is due to editing mistake i didnt know enter submits the comment sorry

Comment: plz suggest a program ? bash is present in windows ?

Comment: @slhck any suggestions?

Comment: @Siva I edited my answer, maybe that helps.

Comment: where can i get this head and tail programs ?

Comment: From GNU core utils

Comment: @slhck: can you provide more info i couldnt make it

Comment: seems the tail syntax is wrong ?

Comment: Works for me, but maybe there's something Windows specific which I couldn't test? And `head` works?

Comment: head command works

Comment: I can't really help you without any further information. `head` and `tail` use exactly the same syntax.

Comment: tail doesnt work i am not sure why... can you think anyother software which can help me do this ?

Comment: Not at the moment, no, I'm sorry!